# What's the best way to write cross platform scripts, like bash in unix?

Tags: windows, shell, unix, scripting, automation

TL;DR: Whats the most optimal way to write portable general-purpose automation scripts for Windows, Mac and Linux?

Longer version:

I work with different platforms and often write shell scripts to automate things (run programs and other scripts, manipulate files and directories, etc).

The problem is that sh/bash substitutes on Windows are tricky, complex, often incompatible or lack some native unix tools. And cygwin scares a regular user, in case when I share some of my scripts with the others.
I find that .bat is very limited and ugly. And I didn't use Powershell a lot, but it looks a bit overcomplicated to me (or should I just give it another try?).

What would you recommend to do in such case? Have you had similar challenges, how did you solve them?

Answer (score 0):

I would advice you use some configuration manager as Ansible, Puppet or Chef. Since their sole purpose is to automate things, and some of them are cross platform. Google each one I mentioned, scripts are generally easy to write in them and they will work on all the platforms, but you will need to install the manager itself on each platform, which can be achieved with init.sh or with a simple powershell script.